# Lemma's needed to proof the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Lemma's needed to proof the fundamental theorem of arithmetic**

I'm reading the proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in my textbook.

The proof is a proof by contradiction and is easy to follow, but they say that there are two lemma's (Lemma 3.4 and Lemma 3.5) needed to proof the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

I do understand all the proofs, but I do not understand in which step of the proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we need lemma 3.4 and lemma 3.5.

Can someone explain that to me?

**Screenshot of the proof in my tekstbook:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: As you can see, the lemma's are not used in the proof you have shown. So your question is the "empty question". Of course, if you go to the next page (uniqueness), then you will need them.

Comment: You will need them for the uniqueness

Comment: You see, now your question is explained in detail in the text.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you explain me why we need n to be the SMALLEST integer that cannot be written as the product of primes?

Comment: Because this shows the existence of a factorization in the first part. We come to the desired contradiction this way.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 3.4 is used to prove lemma 3.5. 
Lemma 3.5 is used to prove the uniqueness of the **Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic**. 
There  $$\prod_{r=1}^u p_{i_r}=\prod_{a=1}^v q_{j_a}$$.
Here , say $p_{i_k},1\leq k\leq u$. Then, $p_{i_k}|\prod_{a=1}^v q_{j_a}\Rightarrow p_{i_k}|q_{j_l}$, for some $l, 1\leq l \leq v$, becuse of lemma 3.5. Sincce both are primes then they must be equal.

Your query about the smallest $n$. We choose **smallest** because then in the $n=ab$, part where $1<a,b<n$, we can say **confidently** that both a and b both foolow fundamental theorem of arithmetic and prevent from considering any $n$.